# jQuery focusout not triggering on exit of input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to fire the focusout event no matter where I click on the document. However i'm using a sortable list which each sortable item contains a textarea, the focusout event isn't fired when clicking on the sortable items. The same occurs for draggable items. I have created a jsfiddle to showcase this issue:

Click on the textarea and attempt to click anywhere within the blue rectangle:
*Tested in Google Chrome*
http://jsfiddle.net/RWJhs/

**Are there any known workarounds?**

JavaScript:

```
$("textarea").focusout(function(){
    alert("Do something");
});

$("#draggable").draggable();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$("textarea").focusout(function(){
    alert("Do something");
}).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;
});

$("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        if( $('textarea:focus', this).length ){
            $('textarea', this).focusout();
        }
    }
}).click(function(e){
    if( $('textarea:focus', this).length ){
        $('textarea', this).focusout();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWJhs/8/)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RWJhs/1/

```
$("textarea").focusout(function(){
    alert("Do something");
});

$('#draggable not(textarea)').on('click');
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

Edit:
Triggering manually the blur event seems to make it work without disabling the draggin
see here: http://jsfiddle.net/RWJhs/6/

```
$("#draggable").on('click', function(e){
    if (e.target == this && $('textarea').is(':focus')) $('textarea').blur();
});
$("textarea").blur(function(){
    alert("Do something");
});
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

Comment: it fixes the focusout issue... but now the item isn't draggable so it's not really fixed

Comment: is it possible to trigger the event as soon as the click occurs rather than after the drag drop event?