# durandal bootstrap knockout not losing focus or updating model

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal

I am using durandal and experiencing an issue where I enter data into a textbox then click a save link and the observable never updates because the textbox never loses focus to trigger knockout to update the observable!

When I click on another input element on the page, then the textbox loses focus and updates correctly. However, then it doesn't save THAT input element's selection. So basically whatever the last field I am in is, is not saving.

Has anyone had this happen to them, and what is causing this horrible behavior? Seems almost like a bootstrap bug because the form elements on the page won't lose focus when you click off of them.

The code I have is as follows:

```
 <div>
                <!-- ko if: $root.selectedFieldId()=='0' -->
                <!-- ko compose:{model:'../tasktype/edittasktype/addedittasktype/index',activationData:{TaskTypeId:$root.TaskTypeId, Sections:$root.Sections,FieldId:$root.selectedFieldId,Dimensions:$root.Dimensions } } --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <button style="float:right;" type="button" class="btn" data-bind="visible:$root.selectedFieldId()==undefined, click:function() {$root.selectedFieldId('0'); }"><span class="icon-plus"></span> Add New Field</button>
                <br style="clear:both;" />
            </div>

            <!-- ko if: addingSection() -->
            <span class="span3">New Section Name</span><input type="text" id="addSection" data-bind="value:newSectionName,event:{blur:addSection }"></input><br />
            <!-- /ko -->
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Drag and drop to reorder the fields below.
            <div data-bind="sortable: {data: Sections,beforeMove:$root.preOrder,afterMove:$root.saveOrder}">
                <div class="item">
                    <h4 data-bind="text:Name" style="margin-left:10px;"></h4>
                    <div data-bind="sortable: {data: Fields,beforeMove:$root.preOrder,afterMove:$root.saveOrder}">
                        <div class="item"><a data-bind="text:Name,click:function() {$root.edit(Id());}" style="margin-left:20px;"></a>
                            <!-- ko if: $root.selectedFieldId()==Id() -->
                            <!-- ko compose:{model:'../tasktype/edittasktype/addedittasktype/index',activationData:{TaskTypeId:$root.TaskTypeId, Sections:$root.Sections,FieldId:$root.selectedFieldId,Dimensions:$root.Dimensions } } --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Interestingly, focus works correctly within form elements in the first compose, but the subsequent ones don't. Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subsequent composes are within "sortable" bindings.  Sortable uses jquery `draggable`, which cancels its `mousedown` event - consequently focus is not moved away from the currently focussed input field.

There are a few questions that cover this topic:

[Why does clicking a drag handle NOT steal away text focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916711/why-does-clicking-a-drag-handle-not-steal-away-text-focus)

[jQuery focusout not triggering on exit of input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631215/jquery-focusout-not-triggering-on-exit-of-input-element)

Comment: You were correct, thank you so much. Although onclick events do not fire, clicking on form type="button" elements still works though...